# Call class method from within class: not enough input arguments

Tags: matlab, class, oop, matlab-class

Let's define the following class with some nested methods:

```
classdef MyClass
    methods(Static)
        function a = simple_func(obj)
            a = obj.simple_func2(1);
        end
        function b = simple_func2(obj,arg1)
            b = arg1+1;
        end
    end
end
```

And call a class method as follow:

```
c = MyClass
a = c.simple_func()
```

I get the following error:

```
Not enough input arguments.

Error in MyClass.simple_func (line 4)
        a = obj.simple_func2(1);

Error in main (line 2)
a = c.simple_func();
```

What is the issue with my class definition? I read so much Matlab documentation that I'm lost now.
I use MATLAB 2023b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined the methods as `Static`, which means that `c.simple_func()` doesn't call `simple_func(c)`, but just `MyClass.simple_func()`. If you remove the `Static` declaration, it'll work as intended.